# SQL select max value with join

Tags: sql

I have two table:

USER (that can have multiple profiles)

```
id | name | profile | ...
```

BET

```
id | profile_id | date | amount | ...
```

I need to select name, and the date of the bet with maximum amount betted for every user from every profile.

So the output should be something like this:

```
name | max_amount | date_max_amount
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

> USER (that can have multiple profiles)

It means that the user can have multiple `id`s and you would be identifying users on the basis of their names and have their max bids

```
SELECT u.name, MAX(b.amount) 
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN BET b ON (u.id = b.profile_id)
GROUP BY u.name
```

Then you can

```
SELECT u.name, d.max_amount, b.date AS date_max_amount
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.name, MAX(b.amount) as max_amount
    FROM USER u
    LEFT JOIN BET b ON (u.id = b.profile_id)
    GROUP BY u.name
)d ON (u.name = d.name)
LEFT JOIN BET b ON (u.id = b.profile_id AND b.amount = d.max_amount)
```